# Redirect to different page after login based on user role with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-security

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Welcome to Akash Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="/webjars/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container text-center">
        <h1>Welcome to the portal</h1>
        <h3>
            <a href="/register">Register</a>
        </h3>
        <h3>
            <a href="show-menu-list-admin">Login as a admin</a><br>
            <a href="show-menu-list-customer">Login as a user</a><br>
            <!--        <a href="login">login</a> -->
            <a href="logout">logout</a>
        </h3>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here I am creating separate links for login as an admin/user. How do I add a single login page that redirects to the next page according to the credential entered for ex: if user1 is an admin if his credentials are entered he will be redirected to the admin page and vise-versa for a user login

*here is my spring security config code :*

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService getUserDetailService() {
        return new UserDetailsServiceImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(this.getUserDetailService());
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }

//  authentication - configure method

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/show-menu-list-admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/show-menu-list-customer").hasRole("USER").and().formLogin().and().csrf().disable();
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi There. What have to tried so far to implement your solution ? Try adding sources or more code sample specific to your situation.

Comment: thanks for pointing this out, i have successfully implemented this feature and next time I will make sure i add more code sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can supply a custom `AuthenticationSuccessHandler`.
The `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` is what tells Spring Security what to do after a successful user authentication.
The default implementation typically uses a `SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler`, which redirects users to the supplied URL once they successfully authenticate.

In your custom implementation, you can delegate to a different `SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler` based on the user's role.

```java
public class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler userSuccessHandler =
            new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler("/user-page");
    SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler adminSuccessHandler =
            new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler("/admin-page");

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = authentication.getAuthorities();
        for (final GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority : authorities) {
            String authorityName = grantedAuthority.getAuthority();
            if (authorityName.equals("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
                // if the user is an ADMIN delegate to the adminSuccessHandler
                this.adminSuccessHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
                return;
            }
        }
        // if the user is not an admin delegate to the userSuccessHandler
        this.userSuccessHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
    }
}
```

Then, supply the `CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler` in the form login configuration.

```
http
    .formLogin(formLogin -> formLogin
        .successHandler(new CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
    );
```