# how to configure Spring Boot Security for Different home Pages for the Role of User and Admin with separate controller for admin and user

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, spring-security-oauth2

I am working on Spring Boot (version 2.5.2) project. I have made Security Configuration
for login page with Thymeleaf. I have One main controller for login page and about page. When a User click on login page, I want the user move on from Main controller to Admin Controller or User Controller URLs to move on their home pages based on their roles respectively.

I have made defaultsuccessUrl in main controller and i check the user role and trying to redirect user to its  respective controller according the his role. However, url is showing in browser but admin or user controller does not  responding to this url and not showing any home page.

I have tried success handler and their i have tried to response.redirect(url) however could not succedded. I will be really thankfull if you guyz could help me pelase.

Please Note that Admin and User Thymeleaf templage pages are in admin and user folders.

```
package com.vu.wcms.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
 import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders
.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
```

import
org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MyConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public UserDetailsService getUserDetailsService() {
    return new UserDetailsServiceImpl();
}

@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider dao = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();

    dao.setUserDetailsService(getUserDetailsService());
    dao.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

    return dao;
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
   http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER")
        .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
        .and().formLogin()
        .loginPage("/")
        .loginProcessingUrl("/doLogin")
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/successHandler")
        .and().csrf().disable();     
}

}

 @GetMapping("/successHandler")
  public String defaultAfterLogin(Authentication authentication) {
   CustomUserDetails userDetails = (CustomUserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();

   String url = "";
   if (userDetails.hasRole("ADMIN")) {
     url = "redirect:/admin/home";
     // return new ModelAndView("redirect:/admin/home");
 } else if (userDetails.hasRole("USER")) {
     url = "redirect:/user/home";
 }

 // return new ModelAndView("redirect:/user/home");

  return url;
```

}

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin")
public class AdminController {

@GetMapping("/home")
public String home(Model model) {
     System.out.println("in admin cotnroller");
     model.addAttribute("title", "Admin Home");

     return "admin/home";
 }
```

}

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

@GetMapping("/home")
public String home(Model model) {
    System.out.println("in user cotnroller");
    model.addAttribute("title", "User Home");

    return "user/home";
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect to different page after login based on user role with Spring Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67520600/redirect-to-different-page-after-login-based-on-user-role-with-spring-security)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer of this question. The problem was in below code.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/user/**").hasAnyAuthority("USER")
        .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
        .and().formLogin().loginPage("/").loginProcessingUrl("/doLogin")
        .successHandler(customAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
        .and().logout().permitAll();
}



  > I was writing hasRole("ADMIN"), but problem solved when i wrote 
   hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")
```